# JAXB does not raise ValidationEvent for second missing mandatory element

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb

JAXB does not raise ValidationEvent for second missing mandatory element

I have an XSD like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Employee" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Employee"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="Employee">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="EmployeeId" type="string"></element>
                <element name="Name" type="string"></element>
                <element name="SecondName" type="string" minOccurs="0"></element>                
                <element name="age">
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base="int">
                            <minInclusive value="18" />
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </element>                     
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>   
</schema>
```

The xml that i am trying to validate and unmarshal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:Employee xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Employee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/Employee SimpleEmployee.xsd ">
    <tns:Junk>Junk</tns:Junk>   
    <tns:EmployeeId>Emp01</tns:EmployeeId>
    <!-- <tns:Name>Hitman</tns:Name> -->
    <tns:SecondName>Hardman</tns:SecondName>
    <tns:age>13</tns:age>
</tns:Employee>
```

I have following Code that collects the error messages and prints.

```
static class ValidationErrorStoringHandler implements ValidationEventHandler
    {
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

        public boolean handleEvent( ValidationEvent arg )
        {
            errors.add( arg.getMessage() );
            return true;
        }

        public void printAllErrors()
        {
            for( String error : errors )
            {
                System.out.println( error );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws SAXException, JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException,
    IOException
    {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( Employee.class );
        Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(
                "C:/ncrdev/workspace/sonartestproject/src/main/resources/SimpleEmployee.xml" );

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setNamespaceAware( true );
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse( fs );

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance( XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI );
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema( new File(
                "C:/ncrdev/workspace/sonartestproject/src/main/resources/SimpleEmployee.xsd" ) );

        unMarshaller.setSchema( schema );

        ValidationErrorStoringHandler handler = new ValidationErrorStoringHandler();

        unMarshaller.setEventHandler( handler );

        Employee emp = ( Employee ) unMarshaller.unmarshal( doc.getFirstChild() );      

        handler.printAllErrors();

    }
```

I see the following out put

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'tns:Junk'. One of '{"http://www.example.org/Employee":EmployeeId}' is expected. 
unexpected element (uri:"http://www.example.org/Employee", local:"Junk"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.org/Employee}EmployeeId>,<{http://www.example.org/Employee}SecondName>,<{http://www.example.org/Employee}Name>,<{http://www.example.org/Employee}age>
cvc-minInclusive-valid: Value '13' is not facet-valid with respect to minInclusive '18' for type '#AnonType_ageEmployee'. cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '13' of element 'tns:age' is not valid.
```

Why is ValidationEvent not raised for the missing mandatory element "Name"?